# INSERT IGNORE vs IN list()

Tags: python, mysql

I have about 20,000 operations I have to do. I need to make sure the 'name' that I have is in the database. Which of the following patterns would be more efficient and why?

(1) in list()

```
cursor.execute('select * from names')
existing_names = [item[0 for item in cursor.fetchall()] # len = 2,000
for item in items:
    if item.name not in existing_names:
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO names VALUES (%s,)', item.name)
```

(2) INSERT IGNORE

```
for item in items:
    cursor.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO names VALUES (%s,)', item.name)
```

Comment: How many rows are in your `names` table as you start this operation?

Comment: Also, what access method are you using (InnoDB?) and what columns are in the table?

Comment: @OllieJones in the names table there are about 2,000 rows. It's using innodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer here is: test, don't guess.

But I'm pretty sure I can guess, because you've got an algorithmic complexity problem here.

Checking `in` against a `list` requires scanning the whole list and comparing every entry. If you do that for 20000 items vs. 2000 list entries, that's 40000000 comparisons. Unless you're skipping almost all 20000 of the SQL statements by doing so, it's almost certainly a pessimization.

However, with one slight change, it might be a useful optimization:

Checking `in` against a `set` is near-instant. If you do that for 20000 items vs. 2000 set entries, that's 20000 hashes and lookups. That could easily be worth saving even just a few thousand SQL queries. If you're on Python 2.7 or later, that's just a matter of `existing_names = { … }` instead of `[ … ]`.

In case you're wondering, inside the database (assuming you have an index on the column), it's using a tree structure, so each look up takes logarithmic time. Even for a binary tree (which is over-estimating the real cost), that's under 11 comparisons for each lookup, which isn't quite as good as 1, but it's a lot better than 2000. (Plus, of course, that search is going to be optimized, because it's one of the core things that databases have to do well.)

And finally, at least with some database libraries, you can get a much bigger speedup by batching the inserts—maybe using `executemany`, or maybe preparing and loading bulk SQL—so you may be optimizing the wrong place anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would use method 2.  However, If you do not have a unique index on names your second method would definitely not insure that your names are unique.

If you need more info on creating a unique index, you can find it [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html).

Your first method would appear to be less efficient then the second due to the fact that you have to first get the list of unique names, then test if it does not match any of them in the loop.

whereas in the second method, maintaining a a unique index may take overall more overhead than the first method, but would probably be more efficient than doing the processing outside the DB. Additional in second method you are only hitting the DB once too.